# post http request to 3rd party server and get response with redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have asp.net mvc project with form I need to send as httpRequestObject.
I'm trying for few days already to make simple XMLhttp request to 3rd party Credit card clearing company url and get back the response with redirect which on XML format - I don't care if redirection made by iframe or popup
checked all over the internet for solutions, tried it on JavaScript - but as far as I understood I'm not able to do it with JS, tried asp.net and  c# also but nothing works for me.
checked all solutions here but still nothing work. 
checked if I'm blocked in any way like proxy or firewall, and it's not the issue.

My current JS code is -

```
function createMPITransaction() {
var terminal_id = "0962832";
var merchant_id = "938";
var user = "my-user";
var password = "my-password";
var url="https://cguat2.creditguard.co.il/xpo/Relay";
var xmlStr = "my string";


var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("POST",url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
http.setRequestHeader('withCredentials', true);
http.setRequestHeader('responseType', 'text');

var response = http.responseText;


http.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
console.log(xmlStr);
console.log(http);
http.send(xmlStr);
```

and getting this from console -

```
 XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: ""…}
```

Am I be able to do it on JS? 
If not, how could I do it on asp.net c#? 
the limitation of request to 3rd party server, and get redirection is not common and make it real challenge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as just the code for redirection is concerned, you can look at similar answer, like for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836811/6298965

What you may be still missing is to check if your request is specification compliant or you're actually getting an error so you're not redirected.

After an initial analysis, I guess that a jsonxml is likely needed for the api call.

Moreover it'd be better if you use or at least look at a github implementation: https://github.com/mderazon/creditguard-node/blob/master/lib/creditguard.js

Comment: thanks
i see that gitHub implementation is with NODE.JS, 
so i can do it with other JS libraries?

Comment: Well... you also tagged your question with c# and asked for a c# solution. There are many different approaches from browserify the node.js module to integrate it with c#: see this other [example](http://juristr.com/blog/2014/03/integrating-node-with-csharp/) ... BTW glad my answer was helpful ;-) ...