# Get URL of page after redirect C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering how I can get the URL of a page after it has redirected from the initial webpage requested.

I am trying to download an image from a url, When I request the page using

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("/getImage");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

The server redirects to another url where the image is hosted(`http://imageHost.co/image-requested`)

Using C# How can I get the url of the page I am redirected to?

Comment: Your question is really confusing.  And you should show the code you've tried so far if you want an answer here.  What is the client?  What's trying to get the redirect URL and download the image?  What is the function?  Is this all in a browser, or some other client?

Comment: @Paul I updated the question. I hope that helps

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836784/how-to-get-a-redirection-response?